# LittleProxy to manipulate request sent and response received

Tags: java, proxy, performance-testing, little-proxy

We have very limited licences, So is it possible that I can fetch same data from Cloud applications via some utility/proxies which can do little data manipulation for us before storing it into our application server.

Consider the usecase, I have only 100 users on GoogleApps and I want to fetch 10K user data.

Can we intercept all request going through e.g. https://localhost:8080/my-app

Now, I want a man in middle i.e. interceptor which can basically cheat our application server that there are N number(e.g. 10K) of users present on Cloud system.

As my Application Server believes that there are still many users present on Cloud system, it will keep generating request for next chunk of user data until we don't cross number N

It will also manipulate the data that is being sent to my application server with incremental number e.g. User1, User2,..., User100, and from next chunk User101,..., User100000 etc.

How can I implemente it using **LittleProxy**

https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy

```
 HttpProxyServer server =
    DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap()
        .withPort(8080)
        .withFiltersSource(new HttpFiltersSourceAdapter() {
            public HttpFilters filterRequest(HttpRequest originalRequest, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
                return new HttpFiltersAdapter(originalRequest) {
                    @Override
                    public HttpResponse clientToProxyRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {

               // ***** HERE I need HELP ******                                

                  }

                    @Override
                    public HttpObject serverToProxyResponse(HttpObject httpObject) {
                        // TODO: implement your filtering here
                        return httpObject;
                    }
                };
            }
        })
        .start();
```

Comment: May be Jmeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html) for generating Users and Burpsuite (https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload) for man in middle i.e. interceptor will work for you, both are free utilities.

Comment: Do you want to generate  big number of user's requests to your Application server or change each request to increase request size? If you want to generate many requests, use some performance testing tool like Jmeter or Gatling, it will be much more easier than proxy server.